# FTP script download from linux to windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, ftp

I'm using following FTP script on windows xp to download zip files from ubuntu cloud servers. A zip file is created every day on ubutnu servers and I will download it to windows via this ftp script.
I run this script everyday manually as I have to edit the last line(mget /usr/backup_02-11-2010.Zip) of the script to match today's date. I want to edit this script so that it will download only today's zip file at the scheduled time without needing to edit it everyday, when scheduled. It's clear that date is appended to the zip files and is in the format dd-mm-yyyy. Need help...

```
open server-ip-here
username-here
user-password-here
lcd C:\Backup\files
bin
hash
prompt  
mget /usr/backup_02-11-2010.zip
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a variable containing your desired date format to your script:

```
set mydate=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%
```

This will echo the current date in format `dd-mm-yyyy`. Then you can use the variable `mydate` to get the actual file:

```
get /usr/backup_%mydate%.Zip
```

Comment: You only need to use `mget` if you have a wildcard in the filename, like `mget backup*.Zip` - normally I'd use plain `get` for an exact filename.

Comment: I'm not sure where to exactly append "set mydate=%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4%" in the script. I added this after the line 'lcd' and its connected but did not do anything.

Comment: I'm getting the error like the following:                           ftp> get /usr/backup_%mydate%.Zip                        
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.                    
550 Failed to open file.

Comment: You need to add that "set" line at the top. Otherwise this will be seen as an ftp command, which it isn't.

Comment: Don't know why! still getting same error.

Comment: Would it be easy if I change windows xp date format

Comment: It's almost done. I checked it using ur above set command for creating a folder and appending the date for it. But the date is in the format mm-dd-yyyy. If you could change the set command to dd-mm-yyy then it's done

Comment: Good to hear that. I corrected the format to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: Useless comment here, but man does that syntax for date suck on Windows! It's a wonder that people even bother scripting with that. `date +"%d-%m-%Y"` ftw

Comment: Yeah, sad but true...

Comment: The set command which you edited now is not working. The previous one`set mydate=%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4%` atleast worked on local windows system when I tested creating a folder and appending a date to it with your set command but now the one which you edited is not even creating a directory.

Comment: I thinks `set mydate=%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4%` worked fine to create a folder of todays date. But not working with ftp script after connecting to ubutnu machine and the out put was still showing `get /usr/backup_%mydate%.zip` and at last failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. If anyone having similar problem, use the below answer. Thanks to Weeheavy!

Answer (score 1):

Here it worked and I copied from the expert 'Weeheavy' to make it work:

```
@REM Beginning of one.bat
@Echo Off
@set mydate=%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-4%

@REM Next write the FTP commands into one.txt

@echo open server-ip-here> one.txt
@echo username-here>> one.txt
@echo password-here>> one.txt
@echo lcd G:\Backup\files>> one.txt
@echo bin>> one.txt
@echo hash>> one.txt
@echo prompt>> one.txt
@echo get /usr/backup_%mydate%.zip>> one.txt

@REM Finally run the FTP command with the one.txt file
ftp -s:one.txt

@REM End of one.bat
```

There should not be any space before `>` or `>>` in the script and in my case the script was failing as I had spaces before them and I was trying this for long.

The script creates a file called one.txt, the first line `...> one.txt` overwrites the one.txt file and the remaining appends to one.txt.

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php